# Django digital ocean droplet isn't showing the website when connected with a namecheap domain

Tags: python, django, nginx, server, digital-ocean

So I'm using a Django Digital Ocean droplet to run a website. I recently tried connecting the IP address of the droplet to a namecheap domain name, but when I connected them it only showed this on the domain:

> Welcome to nginx! If you see this page, the nginx web server is
> successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.
>
> For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
> Commercial support is available at nginx.com.
>
> Thank you for using nginx.

However, the website was working as intended on the IP address, can anyone tell me how to fix this?

my abbreviated `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`file

```
    server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name sanskarhandicrafts.com;       

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;        
    }
 }
```

I'm happy to provide more details

Comment: @Dauros Hey, sorry to bother you again but can you take a look at this problem

Answer (score 0):

remove this line:

```py
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

used below code for location:

```py
location / {
 proxy_pass http://"YOU_IP_ADDRESS":"YOUR_PORT";
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     proxy_redirect off;
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).